# Running and debugging Qt App on Symbian^1 (5800XM)

Tags: linux, qt, symbian, s60-5th-edition

I have a problem with running Qt app on my 5800.
I've installed Qt SDK 1.1.2(As I found it's only SDK version which support Symbian ^1) and compiled sample project using Symbian Toolchain. I use Qt 4.7.3 for Symbian. I've installe AppTRK and CODA on my target phone.
After compiling I tried to run on my phone. Application has been successfully installed on target but it is  can't be runned. I don't know why. Same problem occurs when I use "Create Smart Installer package from projects properties.
After this I've installed Remote Compiler. And the remote compiler's package works fine on my phone. On remote compiler I've also used Qt 4.7.3
What the problem? Why I can't run self-compiled package on my phone?

- Host: Linux Mint(Katya)
- Target: Symbian ^1 5th Edition(Nokia 5800 XpressMusic)
- Qt version: 4.7.3 for Symbian

Here is output after running app using installed on host Qt 4.7.3 and CODA:

```
Connecting to 192.168.1.23:65029... Connected. Launching: myapp.exe
Launch failed: Command answer [command error], 1 values(s) to request:
'C|4|Processes|start|""|"myapp.exe"|[""]|[]|true' 
#0 {"Code":-1,Format="Failed to create the process (verify that the executable and all required DLLs have been transferred) (item not
found)"} Error: 'Failed to create the process (verify that the
executable and all required DLLs have been transferred) (item not
found)' Code: -1 Finished.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think CODA doesn't work if TRK is installed.

Symbian^1 is now called S60v5 in the QtSDK and it's only available via online installer or SDKMaintainanceTool.

Comment: I tried to install QtSDK 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.5 but I can't find option for installing SDK for S60v5! May be it available only on Windows versions?

Comment: Oh, I didn't read carefully. Yes, the Symbian SDK only works on Windows. For all the other platform the only way is to use the remote compiler.